# Alchemy: Get raw SQL string of QueryBuilder

Tags: alchemy-swift

Given the following code:

```swift
Query.table("users").select()
```

I want to get the raw SQL query string that the database query builder above will generate. In this example, it would be `SELECT * FROM users`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an access to the `SQL` of a query which contains the SQL string and any bindings (none in the example above).

```swift
let query = Query.table("users").select()
query.toSQL().query // SELECT * FROM users
query.toSQL().bindings // []
```